# What does this mean in LaTex?

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to read the most recent changes in the C++ Standard on [this page](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/declarations.tex). Very close to top, you'll find the following line of command (I'm just guessing about the name of this entity). What does that mean?

`\indextext{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}`

PS: as you probably noticed, I know nothing about Latex, but at least I could identify that the page in the link shows the paragraphs for the `Section 7 Declarations` in the C++ Standard.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\indextext` macro is not standard, so there should either be a package that defines it or a definition in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\indextext` is not a standard macro; it is defined in `macros.tex` of the sources that you link to as:

```
\newcommand{\indextext}[1]{\index[generalindex]{#1}}
```

such that

```
\indextext{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

is translated to

```
\index[generalindex]{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

using the standard `\index` macro.

So: an entry goes into the `generalindex` (the document maintains some more) using `\index`. The argument for `\index` is processed by a special tool before LaTeX sees it. As you have guessed

```
\index{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

creates an index entry for `linkage specification` that refers to two other index entries: `specification` and `linkage`.

Comment: But why is just one entry being defined here? `Section 7.5 Linkage specifications` is just one of several sub-sections in Section 7 of the Standard.

Comment: Without compiling the document (which seems to require quite some effort, given it's size), I can't tell. That's why providing a minimal working example (MWE) that highlights your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to look at the lines that precede the statement you mention (from `declarations.tex`):

```
%!TEX root = std.tex
\rSec0[dcl.dcl]{Declarations}%
\indextext{declaration|(}

%gram: \rSec1[gram.dcl]{Declarations}
%gram:

\indextext{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

The first line, `%!TEX root = std.tex`, contains a "meta-instruction": It's *not* processed by TeX -- since it starts with the comment character, `%` -- but it's processed by the front-end software (frequently called an "editor"). The meta-instruction informs the editor that if the user clicks on the "Compile" button while the file `declarations.tex` is visible, the document to be compiled is not `declarations.tex` but, rather, `std.tex`. The file `std.tex` (available from the same website as `declarations.tex`) is a "driver" document, which provides the overall document structure and loads files (via `\input` statements) that contain either further setup information or the actual chapters and sections of the document. In `std.tex`, one finds the following instructions:

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,openany,final]{memoir}
...
\input{macros}
...    
\begin{document}
...
\include{declarations}
...
\end{document}
```

where `...` denotes additional, omitted instructions. The file `macros.tex` contains the instruction

```
\newcommand{\indextext}[1]{\index[generalindex]{#1}}
```

Thus, the instruction

```
\indextext{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

is expanded to

```
\index[generalindex]{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}
```

Index creation -- and bibliography creation too, for that matter -- is handled asynchronously by LaTeX: In the first LaTeX pass, each `\index` directive causes index-related meta information to be written to the .aux file (and, depending on the document class, additional files); however, the index itself isn't created at that point. Next, a program such as `makeindex` is invoked to generate an index from the information that's stored in the auxiliary files. Entries in the index (or, possibly, indexes) are usually sorted alphabetically, and that's one of the main reasons that index creation is handled by a program other than LaTeX. (TeX/LaTeX has many built-in capabilities, but speedy sorting isn't among them.) In later LaTeX runs, the index file that was created by `makeindex` is loaded by LaTeX, usually at the very end of the document.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot (+1). Would you be able to explain to me why  is just **one** entry being defined here? `Section 7.5 Linkage specifications` is just one of several sub-sections in `Section 7` of the Standard. That's the point that I'm trying to understand now.

Comment: @Belloc - Not sure I follow you -- I count more than 140 instances of `\indextext` in the file `declarations.tex`. Creating accurate, complete, *and* useful indexes is a non-trivial matter, as I'm sure you can appreciate. I'm afraid I don't know what, precisely, drove the authors to insert the instruction`\indextext{linkage specification|see{specification, linkage}}` at the point where it's located now.

Comment: I was with the wrong idea that all these macro commands would have to come together in a file. But that doesn't seem to be case, as you mentioned above. I think I've got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`macros.tex`](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/macros.tex) file (line 82) you can find the definition of `\indextext`.

```
\newcommand{\indextext}[1]{\index[generalindex]{#1}}
```

It contains one argument and makes use of the `\index` command.